# Neural Network to predict atomic forces using SOAP descriptors

Tags: computational-chemistry, python, machine-learning

I am working on neural network in tensorflow to train a model to predict atomic forces from SOAP descriptors (regression problem).

I have 64 020 data points (chemical structures), each structure has 2718 features - [SOAP descriptor (compressed)](https://singroup.github.io/dscribe/latest/tutorials/descriptors/soap.html). Atomic forces are 3 values - x y z for each direction, they were reshaped into 2D for the model:

```
(64020, 151, 3) -> 64020 structures, each structure has 151 atoms, each atom has 3 atomic forces x y z. 
Atomic forces array shape after reshaping: 
(64020, 453)
```

I also multiplied the values of atomic forces by 1000 (because they are very small values) just to be able to interpret the loss better, but it doesn't have an impact as far as I am aware.

I currently have a network with one hidden layer with 1024 neurons, I experimented with different number of layers and different number of neurons, I use Adam optimizer, I tried drop out, batch normalization, L2 regularization, learning rate scheduler, but I don't see a lot of improvements. What I am seeing that the network is slowly learning, but after some time it gets stuck and just starts oscillating in the local minimum (I assume).
I also use normalization on the SOAP descriptor. A deeper network or more neurons doesn't seem to make a big difference.
I already achieved reasonable results with Kernel Ridge Regression, so I was hoping the neural network would work. But so far, nothing promising has emerged.

Current code:

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(soap_descriptors.shape[1],)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='linear', 
                              kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
 
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(atomic_forces_list.shape[1])
    ])

    initial_learning_rate = 0.001
    lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate,
        decay_steps=10000,
        decay_rate=0.9,
        staircase=True)

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

    soap_descriptors = soap_descriptors.astype(np.float32)
    atomic_forces_list = atomic_forces_list.astype(np.float32)

    s_mean = np.mean(soap_descriptors, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    s_std = np.std(soap_descriptors, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    soap_normalized = (soap_descriptors - s_mean) / (s_std + 0.000001)


    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(soap_normalized, atomic_forces_list, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=1300, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)

    model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
    predicted_forces = model.predict(x_test)
```

[image]

Here, the learning essentially stopped, and the validation loss was no longer decreasing.

When I add one more layer with 512 neurons:

```
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='linear', 
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001)
                              ),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
```

The validation loss reaches 909 around 900th epoch and then just sort of oscillates up and down around that value (907, 908, 906, 911, 912, 913 ..... )

What could such learning process represent? Is there anything else I can try to improve the network? Is the logic trying to predict the atomic forces, without using energies, correct?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but there are already neural network models (like MACE - combination of MPNN neural net and ACE descriptor) that are specifically targeted towards learning atomic forces and energies so might be more suitable for you.

Comment: @SRMaiti Thank you, I will check it out. In my task I had to design my own network and use SOAP descriptor but this might be better solution.